# Build failed due to pom missing during build job in jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, deployment, build

I am trying to build and deploy my project using jenkins. First I deploy jenkins on my system and it works fine. Jenkins was able to build the java project perfectly fine but when I try to configure it on my windows server with the same configuration and setting, build fails.

**Configuration:**

- JDK 1.8
- Jenkins 2.19.4.war
- maven 3.3.9

> Sol 1 - I tried to copy the maven repo from my system to server then it works for few builds but again it start failing.
>
> Sol 2 - Tried to downgrade the maven version to `2.0` but it didnt work as well

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f E:\My-Jenkins\workspace\er4u_test\web\pom.xml clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building web Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for er4u:core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.283 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-17T20:35:56+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.er4u:web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact er4u:core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving E:\My-Jenkins\workspace\er4u_test\web\pom.xml to com.er4u/web/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: make sure that you placed the pom in correct directory

Comment: @Jobin - Jenkins is checking out the code from svn repo to JENKINS_HOME workspace. Please suggest, any changes need to be done from my side?

Comment: what is the root directory of your project?

Comment: @Jobin E:\Jenkins\workspace\demo root directory

Comment: What is this `E:\My-Jenkins\workspace\er4u_test\web\pom.xml` this is there in the console

Comment: @Jobin - My mistake, I copy paste path of jenkins deployed in my system. Correct path is E:\My-Jenkins\workspace\er4u_test\web\pom.xml

Comment: It seems `web` is depent on `er4u` so build  `er4u` first.

Comment: @Jobin - Actually I have two projects on which I am using one project as a dependecy into another. Like this - two projects CORE and WEB, declared core in pom.xml of web. Issue is that everything is working fine on jenkins deployed on my system but on my server with the same configuration, this problem is coming.

Comment: Do the clean install for core first and then web

Comment: @Jobin - thanks, its working now.